# Merging entries in pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas

Suppose I have the following table.

```
import pandas as pd
sales = {'Account': ['Jones LLC', 'Alpha Co', 'Blue Inc'],
         '1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
         '2': ['', 'e, g', 'f, h'],
         '3': ['a', 'g', 'h']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales).set_index('Account')
df
```

Output:

```
               1  2     3
    Account
    Jones LLC  a        a
    Alpha Co   b  e, g  g
    Blue Inc   c  f, h  h
```

I would like to create another column, '4', such that the outcome is the combination from column 1, 2, and 3:

```
           1  2     3   4
Account
Jones LLC  a        a   a
Alpha Co   b  e, g  g   b, e, g
Blue Inc   c  f, h  h   c, f, h
```

I tried using the followings:

```
df['4'] = [', '.join([df['1'][x],df['2'][x],df['3'][x]]) for x in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Output:

```
           1  2     3   4
Account
Jones LLC  a        a   , a
Alpha Co   b  e, g  g   b, e, g, g
Blue Inc   c  f, h  h   c, f, h, h
```

The problems are:

1. in the first row, it's `, a` instead of `a`
2. duplicates: `b, e, g, g` instead of `b, e, g`
3. I need to explicitly write `df['1'][x], df['2'][x], df['3'][x]` instead of define a list `['1','2','3']` and iterate over the list.

I wonder if there is a fast way of doing this without using `df.iterrows()`, checking if any entry is empty, and then combine as appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to exclude the empty columns, and drop the duplicates.

**Code:**

```
df['4'] = [', '.join(sorted(set(sum(
    [[y.strip() for y in df[c][x].split(',')] 
     for c in '123' if df[c][x].strip()], []))))
    for x in range(df.shape[0])]
```

**Test code:**

```
import pandas as pd
sales = {'Account': ['Jones LLC', 'Alpha Co', 'Blue Inc'],
         '1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
         '2': ['', 'e, g', 'f, h'],
         '3': ['a', 'g', 'h']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales).set_index('Account')

df['4'] = [', '.join(sorted(set(sum(
    [[y.strip() for y in df[c][x].split(',')] 
     for c in '123' if df[c][x].strip()], []))))
    for x in range(df.shape[0])]
```

**Results:**

```
           1     2  3        4
Account                       
Jones LLC  a        a        a
Alpha Co   b  e, g  g  b, e, g
Blue Inc   c  f, h  h  c, f, h
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
In [59]: df[4] = (df.replace(r'[\s,]*','',regex=True)
    ...:            .sum(1)
    ...:            .str.extractall(r'(.)')
    ...:            .unstack()
    ...:            .apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.dropna())), axis=1))
    ...:

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
           1     2  3      4
Account
Jones LLC  a        a      a
Alpha Co   b  e, g  g  b,e,g
Blue Inc   c  f, h  h  c,f,h
```